# How to configure my array to perform consider number with decimal as one element?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# input a string 
str = input("Enter the expression: ")
# make an array to check the operator
opArr = ["+","-","*","/"]
# check for operator 
op = ""
for operator in opArr:
    if str.find(operator) == 1:
        op = operator
# split the array
splitStr = str.split(op)
print(splitStr)
# perform mathematical operations
if op == "+":
    result = float(splitStr[0]) + float(splitStr[1])
elif op == "-":
    result = float(splitStr[0]) - float(splitStr[1])
elif op == "*":
    result = float(splitStr[0]) * float(splitStr[1])
elif op == "/":
    result = float(splitStr[0]) / float(splitStr[1])
else:
    result = "Something Went Wrong!!!"

print(result)
```

Here Output is :
Enter an expression: 5+5 // works output is 10

but when I enter 5.0+5 or any other decimal number it prints out an error.

Well, I can see the problem that split() method converts the string into a char array. Is there a way to convert it to a string array or any other way to hold an element like ["5.0", "5"] like that so the output is 10.0 for 5.0+5?

Comment: `str.find(operator) == 1` – Don't expect the operator to be at index `1`…!? You can forego that check entirely, and simply `splitStr = str.split()` and take the operator from `splitStr[1]` instead.

Comment: @Hezen Wing seems like you're doing a simple calculator, try ```eval('your-input-string-expression-goes-here')```

Comment: You can simply do ```if operator in str1:```

Comment: That's not the problem here. The problem is with decimal numbers. I can use eval() simply but I just want to build up an eval like stuff myself.

Comment: The problem with decimal numbers is that they push over the operator to index 3, so your `str.find(operator) == 1` check fails.

Comment: Ah, I got it thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20find#str.find):

> Return the **lowest index** in the string where substring sub is found within the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. Return `-1` if sub is not found.

The problem is that during `5.0+5`, the operator `+` is present on the 3rd index position. But 3 is not equal to 1. So `op` remains the same. And `split` needs some separator on which it could split the string.

You can use `in` operator here which returns `True` if a specific substring is found in the main string.

```
for operator in opArr:
    if operator in str1:
        op = operator
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify for loop. Tips `str.find` return -1 if substring not found.

```
for operator in opArr:
    if str.find(operator) != -1: ## t
        op = operator
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Finally so the problem was that I checked if that find method returns 1 but it should actually checked for not equal to -1.

Answer (score 0):

str.find(operator) returned position of operator. I suggest replacing the condition with if str.find(operator)>0:

```
# input a string
str = input("Enter the expression: ")
# make an array to check the operator
opArr = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
# check for operator
op = ""
for operator in opArr:
    if str.find(operator)>0:
        op = operator
# split the array
splitStr = str.split(op)
print(splitStr)
# perform mathematical operations
if op == "+":
    result = float(splitStr[0]) + float(splitStr[1])
elif op == "-":
    result = float(splitStr[0]) - float(splitStr[1])
elif op == "*":
    result = float(splitStr[0]) * float(splitStr[1])
elif op == "/":
    result = float(splitStr[0]) / float(splitStr[1])
else:
    result = "Something Went Wrong!!!"

print(result)
```